# why conversion can't be done implicite

Tags: c++

The code in line 14 couldn't compile because of the conversion didn't be done, but the code  in 16,17 worked fine due to the explicit conversion operator.

```
  1 
  2 #include <iostream>
  3 using namespace std;
  4 template<typename T,int N>class Array{
  5         private:
  6         T _M_data[N];
  7         public:
----        operator T*(){return _M_data;}
----        operator T(){return _M_data[0];}
++++        T* data(){return _M_data;}
 10 };
 11 int main(int argc,char*argv[])
 12 {
 13         Array<int,5> i5A ;
 14         //printf("%d\n",i5A);   
 15         //won't work,need explicit conversion 
 16         printf("%d\n",i5A.operator int()); 
 17         printf("%p\n",i5A.operator int*());
 18 return 0;
 19 }
```

---

*update:*
I know why standard need a `data()` function: `printf("%d\n",*(i5A.data()));`

Comment: take a look at va_init, the va arguments need to know the type, so the print is done above the type given (%d => int) so the printf imagines that you do the JOB. in C++ the cout uses method overwrite to determinate the same operator<< for all the types. when you give different types the overload establish the correct operator overload

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printf` is a primitive and simple function. It doesn't know what types you pass into it, much less how to convert them. If you specify `"%d"`, it'll just read the parameter you pass as an `int`, spit it out and go on to the next parameter. Or crash. Just don't do it. If you make a promise, keep it - the `%d` is a promise that you're passing in an `int`.

Comment: Great answer!  Yea, printf() has its quirks.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion cannot be done implicitly because in variadic functions like `printf` the format string is parsed by the internals of `printf` at *run-time* and variadic parameter retrieval is performed by the internals of `printf` at *run-time*. For the compiler `"%d\n"` is just a string. The compiler does not parse format string and has no idea how to interpret that format string, so it does not know that the argument needs a conversion and it does not know what type to convert it to.

P.S. Some compilers have the capability to retrieve that information from format string for standard functions, like `printf`. They do it purely for the purposes of error checking. Using this knowledge for implicit parameter conversion is technically possible, but it would produce a rather far-reaching non-standard feature. Such feature has no place in C++. And, of course, compile-time parsing of format string is only possible when that string is actually known at compile-time, which is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

On line 13, there is no implicit conversion. The string format doesn't change the type of the object passed.

Answer (score 0):

The format string you are passing to printf specifies a decimal integer, but you are passing an Array. You need to pass some numeric type that can be converted to an int (or better yet, an actual int). If you want to print multiple values, you may need to loop over the Array and print each element.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` is a varargs function. The types of the arguments to varargs functions are not specified, so there's no way to know what type the arguments should be converted to. There are some default conversions done for some primitive types (e.g. booleans are converted to int). But user-defined conversions will not be done implicitly.